# multifile javascript library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am writing a library that will consist of multiple modules/files. One of the files (let's call it Main) will depend on all other files and so when the user loads this file then the whole library will get loaded.

Now the user may place all of my library in a subfolder (let's call it subdir1), so he configures requirejs like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min",
        "knockout": "Scripts/knockout-2.3.0",
        "MyLib.Main": "subdir1/MyLib.Main"
    }
});
```

In this scenario the subdir1/MyLib.Main.js file will load just fine, but if this file depends on MyLib.Helper module then requirejs will try to load it from MyLib.Helper.js and not subdir1/MyLib.Helper.js file where it is located.

Is there any way to tell requirejs to load submodules from subdir1? I know I can enumerate all those modules in config, but that requires the end-user to know the internal structure of my library (which is not acceptable). Ideally I should be able to enumerate all modules that should be loaded from subdir1 inside MyLib.Main.js file somehow (but note that at this point I cannot hardcode that it will be subdir1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your user to configure a LIBNAME_PATH variable in his require config
Then use this path variable to prefix all your paths

Example:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min",
        "knockout": "Scripts/knockout-2.3.0",
        "MyLib_PATH": "subdir1",
        "MyLib.Main": "subdir1/MyLib.Main"
    }
});
```

Then in `subdir1/MyLib.Main`, you might have something like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "MyLib.Helper": "MyLib_PATH/MyLib.Helper"  
    }
});
```

requirejs should then resolve `MyLib_PATH` to the right path as configured by the user.

This is a super untested draft but i think it should work.
This does imply you have to use this `LIBNAME_PATH` *everywhere* in your library.

Comment: Not ideal as the user has to make two entries in paths array, but still much better than what I could have thought of myself. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative is to pre-build your library with ´r.js´ and then just publish 1 file.

Comment: That is something that I want to do either way for release, but multiple files are better for debugging purposes.

Comment: True True, but you can also build your project into 1 file without minification, this should also be managable for debugging.